# Exclude first match from regex subpattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match pairs of values from a string like `4284{336}1656{595}2961`

I want to match `336` and `1656` as one group of two matches, `595` and `2961` as another, and never match the leading `4284`.

I'm using `( (?<={) .*? (?=}) )* ([^{}]*)*`, but that's matching the `4284`. Please note I've added spaces just to make it more readable. My working example is at https://regex101.com/r/P1kef7/1

How can I exclude the first group? Any one of these groups varies in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the digits between the curly's and the digits direct after it in 2 capture groups:

```
{(\d+)}(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9Huyz/1)

Comment: Yeah but if I don't make it complicated, it'll look like I'm not earning my pay! Ha, thanks for making it easy.

Comment: Why did it take so long for you to come up with a solution?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Maybe the years are starting to count, or the number of parenthesis :-)

Comment: Ok, just for instance...what if I DID want to capture the `4284` and distinguish it from the second groups?

Comment: @oxwilder There are multiple ways to do that, for example using an alternation `(\d+)|{(\d+)}(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/chwKVi/1 Are you using a specific tool or language?

Comment: Ah yep, that does it. I'm trying to classify/declassify strings to various table IDs in PHP. I'm gonna dress it up with a few more parentheses though 

Comment: @oxwilder If you want to match them sequential in php from the start of the string, you can also use the `\G` anchor like `(?:^(\d+)|\G(?!^)){(\d+)}(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/KWPfEj/1

Comment: Ah wow, I never knew about that anchor! That answers quite a few other questions. Thanks again!